# Get basic profile from Twitter without request limit

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

Is it possible to fetch and display basic Twitter profile information without request limits?

On my website I want to display

- Display name
- Profile image
- Verified status

properties of a Twitter handle. Since this website will serve thousands of requests per minute, and users will not sign in through Twitter, I need to get these details without authentication / request limits.

Do I have to fetch the profile page and scrape it on client side (JS) for this or is there any other way?

Comment: With "GET users/lookup" you can get 100 users per second with the public API. Isn't it enough ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can do.

For images, use https://www.avatars.io/ - all that requires is a screen name.  My avatar is https://avatars.io/twitter/edent/medium

You can use [users/show](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show.html) and cache the results.  The rate limits are **900** every 15 minutes.